# Looking for JQuery style web control to drill down a tree data structure

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm looking for a JQuery-style javascript/CSS control that will allow the user to drill down into the workings of an expression.

For example, imagine we have the following expression:

```
  (2+3) × (4+5) + Max(22, 31, 16, 62, 40)
```

This would evaluate as follows:

```
   (((2+3)×(4+5))+Max(22, 31, 16, 62, 40))  
 ⇒ ((5×9)+62)  
 ⇒ (45+62)  
 ⇒ 107
```

I'd like to present these intermediate steps in such a way that the user can drill down a particular evaluation branch to discover the inputs which produced a particular value.

I've toyed with the idea of manipulating the expression's workings into a tree structure, perhaps with intermediate evaluations inserted (shown in blue in the example). However, I'm concerned that the audience to which I'm aiming this software may find this a little intimidating.

e.g.
[image: Expression Tree]

An alternative, friendlier representation could be to allow in-place drill down as shown in this example:

*The expression initially looks like this:*
[image: Expression's initial state]

*User clicks the '107' button which changes the control to this:*

[image: View after the '107' button has been pressed]

*User clicks the '62' button which changes the control to this:*

[image: View after the '62' button has been pressed]

Before I write my own control I thought there may be an existing control available that could be used for this purpose. Alternatively, I'd really appreciate any alternative suggestions for representing this data in a way that may be more intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a control that worked how I described above so I created one.
The source is available at:
http://github.com/Wheelies/expression-explorer

The control is initialized with a tree data structure which can be navigated by the user.

The expression `(((2+3)×(4+5))+Max(20+2, 31, 16, 62, 40))` can be parsed into a tree which may be explored as follows:

[image: 107]

User clicks the `[107]` button which changes the control to this:

[image: 45+62]

`[62]` button is clicked which changes the control to this:

[image: 45 + Max(22, 31, 16, 62, 40)]

User now clicks `[22]`

[image: 45 + Max((20+2), 31, 16, 62, 40)]

*Please note that expression parsing isn't handled by this control. Also, I haven't implemented the control as a true JQuery plugin yet*